Missing Data after Converting Icosahedral Grib to Lon/Lat-Coordinates
I want to process Weather-Forcast-Data from the ICON-D2 model of the DWD. For that I have to convert the data from Icosahedral to the traditional latitude-longitude. For the conversion I use a converter from the DWD, and than get the data for a specific location with a simple python script using (pygrib), This works fine for most data, however when I convert eps data for total accumulated precipitation, I get only 4 values (one for every quarter of an hour). EPS data should however be 20 datapoints per time point (20 independent runs of a model with slightly different starting parameters). When I look at the icosahedral grib2 file I do see 20 points.
So I am currently unsure where the data went. Do I lose them during the conversion, or is it still in the converted grib file and I just look at it the wrong way. (Again, it worked fine for other type of eps data e.g. temperature).
Below is my python script which looks at the lat-lon-grib2 files. Is there some kind of grib2 layer, which I ignore with my approach? Is there a simple tool which just shows all the data for a given location? I am completely new to the grib-format, so any help would be greatly appreciated.
import pygrib
import numpy as np


target_lat = 50.0000
target_lon = 7.0000

# Open the GRIB file
# https://opendata.dwd.de/weather/nwp/icon-d2-eps/grib/15/tot_prec/
file_path = "regridded_eps_germany_icosahedral_single-level_20241017_15_000_2d_tot_prec.grib2"
grbs = pygrib.open(file_path)


for grb in grbs:
    lats, lons = grb.latlons()
    distance_squared = (lats - target_lat)**2 + (lons - target_lon)**2

    # Find the index of the minimum distance
    min_index = np.unravel_index(np.argmin(distance_squared), lats.shape)

    nearest_lat = lats[min_index]
    nearest_lon = lons[min_index]
    data, lats, lons = grb.data(lat1=nearest_lat,lat2=nearest_lat,lon1=nearest_lon,lon2=nearest_lon)
    
    print(float(data[0][0]))  
    print(grb)

# Close the GRIB file
grbs.close()

